# Vue-router's last visited nested route still being active after redirected

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In deep routing pattern nested route changing without a problem, but when I go to parent and come back to the nested child via redirect from the parent. The redirect is not applied smoothly. Path is changing clearly, but page is still displays the last visited nested route. And when I check the vue devtool. I see that redirected route being inactive but last visited is being active.

```js
export default [      
  {
    path: '/1/',
    name: 'sumaipad',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "group-sumaipad" */ './views/index.vue'),
    redirect:"/1/slideshow",
    children: [
      {
         path:"/1/vista",
         name: "vista",
         meta: {
            order: 1
         },
         component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "group-sumaipad" */ './views/vista.vue'),
      },
      {
        path: '/1/plans',
        name: 'plans',
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "group-sumaipad" */ './views/plans.vue'),
        redirect:{name:"rooms"},
        meta:{
          order: 2,
        },
        children:[
          {
            path: 'rooms',
            name: 'rooms',
            component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "group-plans" */ './views/plans/rooms.vue'),
            children:[
              {
                path: ':id',
                name: 'room',
                component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "group-plans" */ './views/plans/room.vue'),
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            path: 'land',
            name: 'land',
            component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "group-plans" */ './views/plans/land.vue'),
          },
          {
            path: 'floor',
            name: 'floor',
            component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "group-plans" */ './views/plans/floor.vue'),
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

For example when I go to `plans` it redirected to the `rooms` without a problem and after that I visit it's sibling which is `land` route and I turn back to parent level's route `vista` again.

THEN if go the `plans` I would expect to redirect me to `rooms` AND its actually is redirect me. The path is changing **but** content is being `land` in nested level. Because I visited it lastly. So even if its redirecting me to `rooms`, the rooms route is being inactive in vue devtools.

Is there a way to change the **active** and **inactive** route about last visited after the redirect?

Comment: Check the browser console for errors. Sometimes `<keep-alive>` also creates unexpected side effects.

Comment: nope, no error. @IVOGELOV

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on CodeSandbox?